# How to connect SD Card Reader to Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: gpio, sd-card, pi-zero-w

I found a MicroSD card reader module working with SPI. Is it possible to connect it to Raspberry Pi Zero W via GPIO?

[Module scheme](http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/8/83/Micro-SD-Storage-Board-Schematic.pdf)

**EDIT:** The module can also be connected via SDIO pins. Which of these two methods (SPI or SDIO) would get the most performance for card reader?

[image: SD Card Reader]

Answer (score 1):

Here is SDIO pinout at Raspberry Pi end:

[image]

To answer you question about performance, SDIO will get you better performance over SPI.

Reference: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sdio

Answer (score 0):

You can enable your SPI configuration through **#sudo raspi-config** and then wire it with your Pi Zero W.
You can look up more via this post, is this what you're looking for ?

[How can I wire this SD card reader to RaspberryPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28648/how-can-i-wire-this-sd-card-reader-to-raspberrypi)

Comment: I saw this post earlier, but the pins description on the module that I have is more related to SDIO than SPI. The only problem is that I cannot find which pins in Raspberry Pi Zero W are intended for SDIO.